# Android application architecture - fragments

Tags: android, architecture, android-fragments

Given the fact that I don't have very extensive experience when it comes to Android apps, I have a questions regarding the architecture of an application :

Are there any problems I can run into if I decide to create an application that has only one activity and I 'load' all the other content using fragments only ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this approach is absolutely all right. More than that, `Fragments` are more lightweight then `Activities`, so you can gain performance by using this approach. However, keep in mind, that `Activity` is designed to behave as a single user screen that serves for a concrete purpose, and `Fragments` are the parts of this screen. So your approach works well if the whole application should contain a single user screen according to the design, thus serving for a single concrete and properly defined purpose.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Initially I designed my app using only activities (I had about 9/10 activities) but no I've added I sliding menu and I don't really like the fell of the app when it opens another activity when I click something from the sliding menu (or an item from a list fragment). It looks and feels so much better with fragments. Bottom line: I should be ok with this approach ?

Comment: @Mihai, Yes, this a fine approach in all respects.

Comment: Thank you for your help - Multumesc pentru ajutor :)

Comment: @Egor What about use of fragment in replacement of TabActivity (depecated)? I mean if we try this approach for app like 1st activity and then click of button --> going in another fragments which holds a list --> on item click --> going in tabactivity ; Ex. list of topics --> list of Question --> tabactivity containing answer / scorecard(voting/polling) ... This is having activity everywhere for the moment.... Can this be fit with one Activity and rest of screen in fragments ???